# Android: how to do a simple POST request with Volley, without expected result?

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I want to send a POST request to my server, and there is no expected data for the result (just HTTP status code - standard behavior). How can I do that ?

(abstract base Request class (Volley) wants a result type)

```
try {
        mRequest =
                new XXXXXX(
                        Request.Method.POST,
                        url,
                        null, null,
                        new Response.Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse() {
                                // ok
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                                // ko
                            }
                        },
                        null
                );

        return mRestCoreVolley.addToRequestQueue(mRequest);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like in the code below for the response listener:

```
new Response.Listener<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Void response) {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is right. You can use a String like:

```
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
                            your_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // do nothing
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Handle error

    }
}) ;
```

Hope it helps you!